# Error in Remix OS during boot after update, i.e. menu.Ist

Tags: android

**1.** Installed **Remix OS 3.0** With official supported tool i.e., RemixUSBTool. On Hard Drive Partition.

**What Actually Happened ?**

**2.** `After Installing` **->** `Working Normally` **->** `Download Updates` **->** `Reboot` **->** `After Installing Updates` **->** `Rebooted Again` **->** `Got Following Error` **--->**

```
find --set-root --ignore-floppies /menu.lst
 error 15:File Not Found 
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here's some more information (in case needed)

- Triple-booted computer with Windows 10, Ubuntu 16.10 & This One.
- Ubuntu stopped working after the above error. (But I fixed this with EasyBSD). Also, after that error, the **RemixOS folder is inaccessible** from Windows 10 (and from other OSes as well.)

  ---

So, does anybody have any solution for it?

(I've already tried a solution suggested on googlegroupchat, but it doesn't work for me.)

Comment: Remix os folder can not access via windows. Windows does not support EXT * or similar types.

Comment: Remix OS was discontinued. The last "download" was  November 25, 2016.

Answer (score 0):

go to remix OS folder and copy 'menu.1st' file and paste it outside the remixos folder. Then Restart your PC.
If your Remix OS folder is inaccessible then Run CHKDSK on that drive via "properties>> Tools" or Via CMD.